# Nested if functions in arrayformula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, nested-if

I have this formula (1) in Google sheets:

```
=IF($A2="","",IF(AND(($G2 <= EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5)),($G2 <> ""),OR($H2 > EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),$H2 = ""),OR($E2 > EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),$E2 = "")),1,0))
```

which I want to convert to an arrayformula. I tried this formula (2) but I get a "#N/A no match" error:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA ( 
    IFs (
        ROW(A:A) = 1, "Contract Published, " & TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-5),"mmm-YY"),
        IF(AND((G:G <= EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5)),(G:G <> ""),OR(H:H > EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),H:H = ""),OR(E:E > EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),E:E = "")),1,0),)
)
```

I also tried this formula (3), but get a "Formula parse error"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA ( 
        IF(ROW(A:A) = 1, "Contract Published, " & TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-5),"mmm-YY")),
        IF((G:G <= EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),G:G <> ""),
        IF((H:H > EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),H:H = ""), 
        IF((E:E > EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),E:E = "")),1,0)))
```

Does anyone have an idea what Im doing wrong, or how I can convert formula (1) into an Arrayformula?

Comment: Does formula (1) work as you wish ? That doesn't seem coherent. May be `=IF($A2="","",IF(AND(
OR($G2 <= EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),($G2 <> ""),
OR($H2 > EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),$H2 = ""),
OR($E2 > EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5),$E2 = "")
)),1,0))` ?

Comment: Yes, formula (1) works fine, but Im trying to change it into an arrayformula, so when new data is added to the sheet, they're calculated automatically.

Comment: Can you provide a spreadsheet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 IF(((G2:G <= EOMONTH(TODAY(), -5))* 
     (G2:G <> "")*
     ((H2:H > EOMONTH(TODAY(), -5)) + (H2:H = ""))*
     ((E2:E > EOMONTH(TODAY(), -5)) + (E2:E = ""))), 1, 0)))
```